# Click on a tab element inside a webpage is not working

Tags: c#, selenium, tabs

I have been trying to click an element in a webpage by using this code

```
var testset = driver.FindElements(By.PartialLinkText("Reversal Detail Overview")) ;
testset[0].Click();
```

But when I am trying to click the element using the exact text shown in the Jscript of the page it is clicking some other element(Yellow color in the picture) inside the active tab but not the seperate tab(Green color in the picture)

[image]

when debugging I am getting the correct tag name of the another TAB

[image]

Not sure where I am going wrong. Can anyone please help me to click on the reversal detail overview tab control that is highlighted in green. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share a link to that page?

Comment: I am really sorry I cannot do that as it will only be connected with a VPN that was installed in our Laptop org. not others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any specific reason why are you `PartialLinkText`  and `findElements` ?

Did you try this instead  :

```
var testset = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Reversal Detail Overview")) ;
testset.Click();
```

if not this, you may even try this  :

```
var testset = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li a[href*='#reversal_detail_overview']")) ;
testset.Click();
```

Comment: No particular reason to find it using partial link text and find elements as I just wanted something to be pull where I am pretty sure cannot go wrong.
The first one I did try @Cruisepandey it was clicking the other window as i posted in my question.
and the second one you mentioned it is showing 'no such element: Unable to locate element. I did try that method as well

Comment: my bad, I updated the css selector `li a[href*='#reversal_detail_overview']` to this, try again.

Comment: That is still clicking the below tab which was highlighted in the question as yellow. 
can it be because it contains the word reversal detail as well? the script for the element which is being clicked is <div class="col-md-11">Reversal Overview&nbsp;</div>

Comment: do this go to dev tools by pressing F12, then go to element section and do CTRL + F and type the same css `li a[href*='#reversal_detail_overview']` and see which one is getting highlighted

Comment: It is highlighting the correct element but when sending a click it clicking something else. from my experience what I think is the elements are not in a organized way and the other thing i guess is the other element has a half text of the item we are searching hence clicking on an active element tab instead of activating another tab

Comment: one more thing, how many entries do you see  ? that should be written on the right hand side of search bar like 1/1 or 1/2 or 1/5 and so on..

Comment: There are no entries, if you are asking about the elements in them there are 2

Comment: the moment you type this into search bar `li a[href*='#reversal_detail_overview']`, you would see a count either 0/0 , 1/2 something like that, what is that value ?

Comment: is it highlighting the one you are looking for or the other one ?

Comment: Yes. It  is highlighting.

Comment: That did not answer my question, I know it's highlighting :) but which one ?

Comment: I am sorry, I mean Yes that is highlighting the element what I am trying to fetch.

Comment: since it's highlighting the one we are looking for and you say it 1/1 in the console, I do not see any reason that the above code should not work. Is there a way I can see your code little widely or  your production URL